# How to inspect electron project to change css

Tags: javascript, css, electron

I am going to change some css in electron.js
I successfully ran electron project by `npm start`.
But I want to inspect like web to change css.
Is there any way?

Comment: Please read [ask] and add some [mre]

Comment: What did you try?